# In Play Framework, how to exclude files when packaging?

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am using Play 2.5.

When I run `sbt package`, the routes, config and log config file will be included in the final package.

How can I manage which file to include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain what you are planning to achieve? I know that play does not allow you to remove the routes and confs file. There are plenty of approaches but I believe that the sbt native packager could be of help to you.

You can check more here : 
http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html

This allows you to modify your generated artifact.

Comment: Thx, I will read your link! My problem is that when I package, the routes file will be included in the `.zip` file but I don't want to expose the routes to the user.

Comment: hmm.. I'm not sure if that is possible, however, can you tell me why you don't want the user to know your api routes? Out of pure curiousity. I can understand why you wouldn't want your configs exposed

Comment: I just think it's meaningless. Also the `.bat` file, I want to keep my package clean and simple so I want to get rid of every thing I think useless.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I applied `tar` option in `build.sbt` like this:

```
universalArchiveOptions in (Universal, packageZipTarball) :=
  (Seq("--exclude", "routes") ++ (universalArchiveOptions in (Universal, 
packageZipTarball)).value)
```

For my package is .tar, in your case please modify this filed.

Comment: Ah, nice solution! Probably will use it too :)